# Can I somehow get the fetch response in the first `then`?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am trying to use the Fetch API. It seems from examples that a GET request needs one `then` to parse the response somehow.

Currently I am doing this

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);  
    });
```

However that first `then` seems like a boilerplate. I tried to avoid it, for example:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.json());  
    });
```

But this logs me a pending `Promise` with status `resolved`.

I read other questions on this topic and read a bit about promises, but I couldn't understand if it's possible to combine it in a single `then` (if so - how?) or not.

For example, two of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540134/understanding-fetch-in-js) point out that

> There is no need to use more than one '.then'

and

> there is no good reason to have two .then() handlers as the code from each could have been combined into a single .then() handler

But I couldn't get that example to actually work - I still got a promise :)

On the contrary, the accepted anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/promise-pending) explains that `.then` actually does something to the result (extracts the returned from promise), but I couldn't unserstand if I can somehow do that myself, say `response.json().then()` or `response.json().getVal()` or is the double-`then` syntax the only way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's quite simple: when you dispatch the a `fetch()` request, it returns a promise containing the response. That is resolved by the first `.then()`. Resolving this first promise actually returns `Response`.

Now this is the tricky part: the methods that read the body of the response, be it `.json()`, `.text()`, `.blob()`.... **all return promises**. This means that you will need to resolve the second promise in order to get the parsed response.

The flow looks like this:

1. Make a `fetch()` request, and it returns a Promise of type `Response`
2. When you attempt to resolve the content of the Response, it will return a second Promise, whose type depends on the method you use (e.g. `.json()` returns an object, `.text()` returns string, `.blob()` returns Blob).
3. Resolve the second Promise, and you get your actual parsed response body

p/s: If you're not using `fetch()` in a top-level context (as of the time of writing top-level await is still not a thing), then you can use async/await to make your code a little more readable:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const content = await response.json();
console.log(content);
```

Comment: Ah, the tricky part is exactly what was a bit too tricky to get it myself :)  So it's either chaining or nesting `response.json().then(r => {console.log(r)})`.

Comment: @Džuris Precisely. I would not encourage nesting because it defeats the purpose of daisy-chaining promises (which is a lot prettier/more readable).

Comment: Thanks for the above clarification, @Terry. I'm a bit confused on 1 point. Does the Response in the first Promise contain the HTTP response body from the 'get go'. I'm wondering why it was designed in such a way that you need to fetch another Promise to get at the body. What's it actually doing, under the hood? Tx :)

Comment: I like this solution, but am I correct in assuming that doing it this way you lose the ability to use the "catch"?  Or can it still be done?  And why did they make it this way instead of just returning the response object ready to go?  Why the need for the French Taunter?  Is there something you are going to do with the response other than read it?

Answer (score 2):

The first promise returned by `fetch` can be useful in some cases. If you want to avoid boilerplate, you could simply create your own function:

```
function fetch_json(url, opts) {
    return fetch(url, opts)
        .then(resp => resp.json());
}

fetch_json(your_url)
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: This is what I would recommend.  It avoids repeating the same code over and over again.  When you just want the JSON, you can just use this one utility function.

Answer (score 2):

These days I am using the async/await syntax which is the same thing, but looks less like a boilerplate to me.

```js
const response = await fetch(url)
const data = await response.json()

console.log(data)
```